# Get data in batch using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I create Rails APP and I would like to fetch data batch starting from specific point. I use AR and my table structure looks following:

```
create_table(:types) do |t|
  t.string      :name,      null: false
  t.string      :type,      null: false
  t.string      :type_id,   null: false
  t.text        :metadata
  t.timestamps
end
```

To get data I use type_id which is in following format (GUID):

```
"b2d506fd-409d-4ec7-b02f-c6d2295c7edd"
```

I would like to fetch specific count of data, ascending or descending ,starting from specific type_id. To be more specific I want do do something like this:

```
Model.get_batch(type_id: type, count: 20).desc
```

Can I do it simply in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord::Batches to find records in batches

example

```
Model.where('your condition').find_in_batches(start: 2000, batch_size: 2000) do |group|
  # do something with batch
end
```

check also [ActiveRecord::Batches.find_in_batch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches)

Comment: But here I can't specify type_id (which is string) as starting point

Comment: You don't need to if you're processing everything.  If you're only processing from that point onward:  Model.where('id > ?', Model.find(:type_id => "GUID goes here").id).find_in_batches...

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following

`Model.find_by_type_id(type).offset(batch_offset).limit(amount_in_batch)`

Or as on answer above

```
Model.where(type_id: your_value).find_in_batches(start: 2000, batch_size: 2000) do |group|
  # do something with batch
end
```

Comment: ok I understand. But is there any possibility to get some count of entries starting from some id BACKWARD?

Comment: you can use `reverse` method. That will make you to select forward, since array on objects will be reversed